# GetFileDropList is empty in when PowerShell script invoked from C# console app

Tags: c#, powershell

For some reason this script does not work in this code:

```
public class PowerShellTest
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        string scriptText = "$F = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetFileDropList(); $F;";
        //string co = "\"D:\\\"";
        //co = "$Dirs = [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(" + co + "); ";
        //co = co + " $Dirs;";
        //scriptText = co;
        using( PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() )
        {
            ps.AddScript(scriptText, true);
            var x = ps.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't return anything and the `PSObject` collection count is `0`.

However it works when I run it in the PowerShell ISE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please be a little more detailed that `does not work`. Maybe throw in a `$F -eq $null` test of sorts

Comment: Does the script work in the ISE?

Comment: Did you load the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly?

Comment: When debugging, does ps have any errors? if so what does ps.Streams.Error contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the clipboard you need to ensure your PowerShell instance starts in `STA` or Single Threaded Apartment mode and also make sure you've referenced the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly.

To do this:

```
string scriptText = @"
  Add-Type -an System.Windows.Forms | Out-Null;
  $f = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetFileDropList(); 
  $f;
";

using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PSInvocationSettings psiSettings = new PSInvocationSettings();
    psiSettings.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;

    ps.AddScript(scriptText, true);
    var x = ps.Invoke(null, psiSettings);
}
```

If you were trying to do this directly from a .NET Console application you'd need to do the same thing:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
        Console.WriteLine(f.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell ISE loads the Windows Forms type automatically, but the PowerShell command line doesn't.  Use the following line in the script before you try to do anything with the clipboard object.

```
add-type -an system.windows.forms
```